# WCF send and receive string?

Tags: wcf

im able to successfully use an MSDN example on sending a message to an MSMQ and reading it from a self hosted WCF service.

I am trying to use a simple string in a new project. I can send the string to the queue no problem but the WCF service hosted, faults.

After trying to figure out why, using the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer and enabling logging on the host, it says its a poison message!

but my contract defines MsmqMessage

This is what I am using to send:

```
System.Messaging.Message msg = new System.Messaging.Message(this.textBox1.Text);
```

And this is my contract (receiving):

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")] void
 ProcessIncomingMessage(MsmqMessage<string> incomingMessage);
```

The content of the message when looking through MMC:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>test</string>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Fixed: on the sender, define the formatter:

    msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new string[] { "System.String" }); 

on the contract, decorate it with a knowntype of string:


    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(String))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: on the sender, define the formatter: msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new string[] { "System.String" }); on the contract, decorate it with a knowntype of string: [ServiceKnownType(typeof(String))]